# css transform + css transition = skipped frames [Google Chrome]

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-transforms

When I click on the scene, then box falls down. When I click again, box stands up. Animation is smooth, but when I click many times in different positions, then sometimes animation skips frames.

I have this bug on OS X in Google Chrome. Tested in Opera — everything is ok, there is no bug.

[image: show]

http://jsfiddle.net/nw78myhn/1/

Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.scene {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #efefef;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transition: transform 600ms linear;
}

.box-transform {
  transform: rotate(-96deg);
}
```

```js
$('.scene').on('click', function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('box-transform');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I've noticed that there is no frame skipping if `transform-origin` is set for `.box-transform` instead of `.box`:

http://jsfiddle.net/nw78myhn/2/

But in this case origin is not visually at `bottom left`. And I don't really understand why.

**UPDATE 2 [16 February 2016]:**
This bug was fixed in newer versions of Google Chrome. Can't reproduce in  Chrome 48.0.2564.109

Comment: Hi, I use MAC OS X and google chrome and can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi, try to click different points of the scene

Comment: @imkost hi it is even replicate on chrome having windows 8 i just checked out some time it missed out a frame or we can say smoothness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a Chrome bug related to transitioning a single property.

To make your second example suit your needs, you can add a silly transition

```js
$('.scene').on('click', function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('box-transform');
});
```

```css
.scene {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #efefef;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transition-property: transform perspective;
    transition-duration: 600ms;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: initial;
}

.box-transform {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
    perspective: 1001px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scene">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, man, it does work! I reported an issue to Google Chrome.

Comment: StackOverflow says, that I need to wait for 15 hours before awarding bounty.

Comment: Don't worry !   Happy that it helped :-)

Comment: @imkost Can you please post the link of the bug report here?

Comment: @Rowno, sorry, I don't know how to get a link. I just did this: "Chrome -> Help and About -> Report an issue..." By the way, I still have no response from Google. Probably I have to find Chrome's bug tracker website and post there.