# Is there a way to have a smooth animation always happening on hover with translate3d?

Tags: css, hover, css-animations, translate3d

- I have a CSS layout with a right-side menu (in green).
- The main part of the menu is by default hidden outside the viewport.
- On mouse over on the right side menu: after a short delay, the menu translates fully into the viewport (after a little delay).
- On mouse out on the right side menu: the menu should translate back to its initial position (no delay).

See the green menu on this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuacxfn1/): **try to hover the green menu**

Here is the relevant CSS code:

```
section#base-layer section#base-layer-contact-bar {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 60px;
    right: -90px;
    width: 150px;
    height: calc(100% -  60px);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in;
    background-color: green;
}
section#base-layer section#base-layer-contact-bar:hover {
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

**To reproduce**: move the mouse out of the green colored section while the animation is in its initial state, meaning before it reaches its full extension.

- Is there a way to have a smooth animation always happening?
- Is there a problem with my CSS?
- Is this even possible?
- If so is there a CSS only solution to it, or must I take a different path?

Note I'm using Chrome v45 on ubuntu.

Comment: I cannot see said animation on your jsfiddle, perhaps you missed describing something in there?

Comment: @AGE like described, the animation is on the green menu, and it kicks in after a little delay (on purpose)

Comment: I cannot see any flickering, do you mean when the menu opens and before the animation is done you move your mouse out of the green part the menu jumps back into position? If not I don't know what you mean

Comment: I don't see any flickering, nor the jumping back. When i mouseout it simply animates closed. Must be browser-specific (I'm on osx Chrome). FYI, that delay is just annoying - what users are going to think "ohh lets open the menu - I hope it makes me wait a bit first!" ;)

Comment: @Moob I'm not asking for UX advices obviously I've made all the things slower for debug purpose. You know even the colors will change in the production version ;)

Comment: @SebastienLorber Haha, yeah. I expected as much ;)

Comment: Interestingly, after playing around with it for a bit I found that it I *can* make it snap closed after all, but *only* when rapidly mousing out whilst it is *first* opening. I can flick my cursor in and out of the element whilst its closing without a issue at all.

Comment: its as if the hover event is only recognised on the portion of the element that was already visible, until the transition is complete upon which point all of it responds to the event.

Comment: Check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32207741/1926369 seems to be the same issue

Comment: @vals It works, so post the answer and I would accept it. However I don't understand why :)

Comment: Never mind, it would be a duplicate. There isn't much to understand, it's just a stupid bug in Chrome (with a stupid solution). Hopefully the next version won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

At first I couldn't reproduce your problem.

The only reliable way was when I applied changes to your fiddle and hit `run` the jump started to happen.

When you come to your fiddle on a "fresh" load (**reload the page**), the jump is not happening. Or very very very occasionally, if you move your mouse around fast all the time (which is **not** normal user behaviour).

So I guess while developing this problem can occur while you apply changes to your CSS, but otherwise this should not happen.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I can reproduce it every time actually, which is odd behavior considering your statement

Comment: Yes i can reproduce it everytime too and weither or not normal behavior it will happen for real users and is not sexy UX

Comment: Hm, weird. Well, I at first was having problems reproducing it, this is how I managed. An other thing to mention is that your CSS is a bit over sprecific, but maybe this is just for your example

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. I've simply removed the `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` on the `#base-layer-contact-bar`.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/wuacxfn1/1/

```
section#base-layer section#base-layer-contact-bar {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 60px;
  right: -90px;
  width: 150px;
  height: calc(100% -  60px);
  /* transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); < remove this */
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in;
  background-color: green;
}
```

The problem is I don't really know *why* it works! Perhaps someone smarter than me can furnish us with the answer?

FWIW, [this version](https://jsfiddle.net/fbyftmt3/) using `translateX` also works for me. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have had jumps with both versions :'(

Comment: @SebastienLorber that is frustrating. Can you look at this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wuacxfn1/2/ I've used JS to toggle a .hover class but with a delay on its removal. Does it display the same issues for you? I'm not proposing it as a solution - just doing some detective work.

Comment: Yes I have the issue too. It seems the `:hover` is not the problem here

Comment: What OS + Browser are you using?

Comment: chrome v45 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. Does the animation itself judder or is it that the entering/exiting of the element stops and starts the animation? What's it like for you if you with the extended setTimeout in the following jsFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/wuacxfn1/3/