# Changing css with jQuery 2.1+ ignores transition property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, jquery-2.0

I am switching from jQuery 2.0.3 to 2.1.0.

I noticed that in v2.1.0 the `css transition` property is ignored when setting css properties directly

`$('#someElement').css('width','100px');`

In **v2.0.3** , my element will maintain it's `css` transition, whereas I lose that in **v2.1.0**.

I am wondering why this is treated differently, and how I can 'turn on' the transition effect.

**With jQuery 2.0.3, the css `transition` property takes effect**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.myClass').css('width', '100px');
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

**With jQuery 2.1.0, the css `transition` property is ignored**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.myClass').css('width', '100px');
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

### Edit:

I am seeing this odd behavior in Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m

In Firefox 42.0, both animate properly

Comment: I don't see any differences! May be you have problem with your browser.

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi What browser are you in? I can reproduce the OP's issue in the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: yes, I'm in Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 .  I'll add that to the question

Comment: I'm in the latest version of firefox @JoshCrozier. The transitions go well.

Comment: if I use chrome, I usually add another property to the class. Try to add `-webkit-transition: width 3s` to the class property.

Comment: Weird, I am trying your code on fiddle and everything works fine for both chrome or firefox. But I am not sure why it doesn't work for chrome on SO code snippet. https://jsfiddle.net/z0qLahuu/

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi  didn't seem to do the trick

Comment: @choz it seems ondomready vs onload was causing the discrepency.  2.1.0 only worked with onload, whereas 2.0.3 worked with both

Comment: @EricPhillips It's probably similar issue to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161553/css-transform-css-transition-skipped-frames-google-chrome and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451756

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching around, I think this may be related to the changes made for issue [#14164](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14164) during the [v2.1.0 release](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/). As per the title, ["Reduce forced layout reflows in init or methods"](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14164).

I compared the [v2.0.3 source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js) with the [v2.1.0 source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js), and it looks like some refactoring was done around the `.ready()` method and how the events are deferred. More specifically, I think it may be related to line(s) 3407-3408 in v2.1.0 where the `.ready()` method is initially invoked (this wasn't present in v2.0.3):

```
// Kick off the DOM ready check even if the user does not
jQuery.ready.promise();
```

---

As for a workaround, it seems like this transition behavior is inconsistent across browsers. To resolve the issue in Chrome, you could defer the execution of the code and force a redraw.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.myClass').css('width', '100px');
}, 0);
```

```css
.myClass {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also load jQuery *after* the DOM elements by moving the script to the bottom of your page. It's still baffling why this makes a difference in Chrome, but doesn't matter in Firefox; it must be related to how the DOM is drawn/painted after events.

```js
$('.myClass').css('width', '100px');
```

```css
.myClass {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're right, it seems `2.1.0` in Chrome doesn't work with `ondomready` , only with `onload`, whereas `2.0.3` works with both https://jsfiddle.net/z0qLahuu/  Strange behavior

Comment: It looks like it also works if you apply the `css` inside `onclick` function like `$('.myClass').on('click', function(){ $('.myClass').css('width', '100px'); });`

Comment: @EricPhillips You're right. I searched around, and it was probably related to the reflow changes made for issue #14164. I updated the answer.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thank you for the incredibly thorough/researched answer, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

it also seems to work using animate() instead of css()

```js
$('.myClass').animate({'width': '100px'});
```

```css
.myClass {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```